# Haproxy 2 domain ssl crt conflit

Tags: linux, hard-drive, database

Haproxy load balancer - I configured 2 different domain SSL certificates and get a conflict. For example I have two domains api.xxx.com  and api.yyy.com. If try to get api.xxx.com its showing yyy cert insecure after refresh xxx crt is showing and yyy domain showing insecure.

This is configuration -

```
global
   maxconn 2000000
   tune.ssl.cachesize 1000000

listen stats 10.0.1.151:8080
    mode http
    log global
    stats enable
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /
    stats hide-version

frontend rserve_frontend
    maxconn 2000000
    bind 10.0.1.144:80 transparent
    bind 10.0.1.144:443 transparent ssl crt /etc/ssl/haproxy/api.xxxx.pem /etc/ssl/haproxy/api.yyy.pem
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    timeout client  10m
    default_backend rserve_backend

backend rserve_backend
    mode tcp
    maxconn 2000000
    option tcplog
    option log-health-checks
    option redispatch
    log global
    balance roundrobin
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout server 5000
    timeout client 50000
    source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip
    server rserve1 10.0.1.189:7000 check
    server rserve2 10.0.1.190:7000 check
    server rserve3 10.0.1.191:7000 check
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please  use proper grammar, punctuation and capitalization. Format configuration snippets  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or use the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability and attracts better answers .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.